# c# Handling events of two instances

Tags: c#, events

I'm using a Panini bank check scanner.
I have a controller that receive differents events from the scanner.
One event looks like this :

```
//Connected
case 0:
    DeviceConnectedEvent?.Invoke(this, vxargs);
    break;
```

And

```
public delegate void DeviceConnectedEventHandler(object sender, VisionXAPIEventArgs e);
public event DeviceConnectedEventHandler DeviceConnectedEvent;
protected void OnDeviceConnectedEvent(object sender, VisionXAPIEventArgs e)
{
    DeviceConnectedEvent(this, e);
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

I have a class in my code that handle all the scanner stuff. Including receiving these events. When initializing this class, I call for each event :

```
scannerAPI.DeviceConnectedEvent += new APIControl.DeviceConnectedEventHandler(ScannerAPI_ScannerConnectEvent);
```

My problem now is that I have two different places in my software that I need this scanner to be called and to scan checks.
When I create a scanner instance I send to him the window that call to link them.
In each window that call the scanner I have a DeviceConnected method, that I want to be called by the class, like this :

```
private void ScannerAPI_ScannerConnectEvent(object sender, VisionXAPIEventArgs e)
{
    //Do some code linked to the scanner
    CallerWindow.ScannerConnecteEvent();
}
```

But when I do this, when I call the scanner scan method, I see that the scanner have the actual window as caller window, and when I receive the event, I see that the scanner window is on the instance of the scanner that is linked to my other window (Main window, the window that call the scanner first).
I don't know if i'm clear enough, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Why are you calling `Application.DoEvents()`?

Comment: I would suggest that you only need one instance of the scanner, btw.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm curious to know why you think I need only one instance. I need to call the scanner from two different spaces in my code, with different behaviour, with different reactions to the events...

Comment: All the retrurns of the scanner are made through events, so I have to handle them directly from the caller window, how to do this with only one instance ?

Comment: Use SingleTon Pattern

Comment: You architecture is poor.  You should get yourself a good communications books and read up on master/slave architectures.  The scanner is a slave device and with current architecture will have issues sending the responses to the correct client when two commands are send simultaneously from two different clients.

Comment: @betsou - It sounds like when you have two instances only one receives the events. That's why you must only have one, but you should share it in two places or make the instance lifetime short so you only have one instance at a time.

Comment: Okay I will try to limit the scanner to only one instance. @jdweng if I have only one instance is it good ?

Comment: One instance should be good, but you will need to be able to handle a busy state when a 2nd process attempts to use scanner.

Comment: @jdweng How do you do this ? You have a link ?

Comment: The easiest way is to make the class that communicates with the scanner to be static since you can only scan one check at a time.  The class should have a busy property that is set when one part of your code calls the scanner the other parts of the code are locked out.

Comment: @jdweng But, without some infinite loops, there is no way to know when the scanner finished his job. The calls don't return any value, there are only these events.

Comment: No true.  The scanner must return some indication when it finished the job.  Either a command or when all the data is received.   The should be a byte count of the received message length.

Comment: Type scannerAPI. (including period).  Is there any events that indicated Complete?

Comment: I've imported myself all the methods from the C# non managed API so I don't think I will find any method I haven't seen before ! There is a document completed event, but can't be sure if it's the last doc or if there is another doc in the scanner that haven't completed yet, and not sure the scanner state is really OK or stucked somewhere...